# What is a good internet based source of information on Hierarchical Modeling?

Tags: modeling, regression, multilevel-analysis

I am talking about the regression method that measures the impact of several layers of independent variables upon a dependent variable.

Comment: Should this be CW as it is asking for a collection of resources? What would constitute a 'correct' answer for such a question?

Comment: I am new here, so I don't know what CW is?  Does it mean Community Wiki or something?  And, what does this mean?  Should I have posted this question somewhere else within this site?  And, where? and how?

Comment: When you ask a question or edit a question there is a check box that appears at the bottom of the question box towards the right hand side that says 'Community wiki'. You need to check that box *if* you wish to make a question or answer CW. The idea behind CW is enable the community to edit the questions/answers collaboratively and to prevent users from gaining rep for certain type of questions. See this link for more details: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-should-our-faq-contain/198#198

Comment: I don't know what starting a bounty mean?  I have been asked to start one.  What are its implications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UCLA has some good resources:

- [Papers on multilevel modelling](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/papers/mlmpapers.htm)
- [Textbook examples](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/examples/) (see multilevel modelling)
- A free textbook on multilevel modelling by [Harvey Goldstein](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/examples/msm_goldstein/)
- and more...

Answer (score 7):

[The Centre for Multilevel Modelling](http://www.cmm.bristol.ac.uk/learning-training/index.shtml) has free online tutorials for multi-level modeling, and they have software tutorials for fitting models in both their MLwiN software and STATA.

You will probably want to check out all the questions with the [multilevel analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multilevel-analysis) tag here. You will find many other suggestions for books and resources.

Also [Harvey Goldstein](http://www.cmm.bristol.ac.uk/team/HG_Personal/multbook1995.pdf) has an online book, but I would suggest you check out the Centre for Multilevel Modelling first.

good luck

Answer (score 4):

I warmly recommend Doug Bate's [book](http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/book/)

Comment: Is Doug Bate's mixed-effects model the same as a hierarchical model?

Comment: yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model